# Run *.jar using specific JRE in Windows 7

Tags: java, jvm

I have both `32-bit` `Java 1.7` and `64-bit` `Java 1.8` in `64-bit Windows 7`. My default java is `64-bit`.

[image]

When I run `*.jar` GUI application by double-clicking, it selects `64-bit java` as default `JVM`. Is there any way to select `32-bit java 1.7` when I double click *.jar file?

Answer (score 0):

You can directly browse to the respected java, example C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_112\bin\java -jar "jarfilename.jar" and run the jar file, it will select java you have mentioned

Comment: Yes I know that I can do that, but I need to automatically select this path if I double-click open the *.jar file.